# Can I use MPI_Barrier() to synchronize data in-between iteration steps

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Is it good idea to use MPI_Barrier() to synchronize data in-between iteration steps. Please see below pseudo code.

```
While(numberIterations< MaxIterations)
{
   MPI_Iprobe() -- check for incoming data
    while(flagprobe !=0)
    {
        MPI_Recv() -- receive data
        MPI_Iprobe() -- loop if more data
    }

   updateData() -- update myData

   for(i=0;i<N;i++) MPI_Bsend_init(request[i]) -- setup request

   for(i=0;i<N;i++) MPI_Start(request[i]) -- send data to all other N processors

   if(numberIterations = MaxIterations/2) 
      MPI_Barrier() -- wait for all processors -- CAN I DO THIS

   numberIterations ++

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Barriers should only be used if the correctness of the program depends on it. From your pseudocode, I can't tell if that's the case, but one barrier halfway through a loop looks very suspect.

Comment: My idea was to wait in between so that all the N processors catchup. Is there any better way to accomplish this??

Comment: Do they **need** to catch up though? Would the program give incorrect results if the barrier wasn't there?

Comment: Nope..but im running in to buffer/deadlock problems with higher iterations. Program works fine up to 6000 iterations. Anything more than that...im out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will deadlock, with or without a barrier.  You receive in every rank before sending any data, so none of the ranks will ever get to a send call.  Most applications will have a call such as `MPI_Allreduce` instead of a barrier after each iteration so all ranks can decide whether an error level is small enough, a task queue is empty, etc. and thus decide whether to terminate.

Comment: Yes sir. I understand that. I updated with exact pseudo-code.

Comment: @Naga: that version still does blocking receives before sends and so will still deadlock.

Comment: I was under impression that MPI_Iprobe will allow me to receive only if there was anything that was sent. what a bummer!

Comment: Can you please explain why I would run into deadlocks with MPI_Iprobe. Thanks for advice.

Comment: I didn't see that you started with an `iprobe`.  Is there some reason you don't want to just pre-post an `irecv` and wait for it to complete?

Comment: I thought this approach would give better performance...but for 6000 iterations or more I am running into buffer/deadlock problems :(((

Answer (score 0):

In this article http://static.msi.umn.edu/rreports/2008/87.pdf it says that you have to call `MPI_Free_request()` before `MPI_Bsend_init()`.